# Symfony4 - Working with db-test

Tags: php, symfony, testing, doctrine, phpunit

I'm unfortunately stuck for few days on one thing..
In my symfony App, I have a 'symfony-db' for my dev and a 'symfony-db-test' which is intended for my tests.

However, I don't know the best practice to do. I'm wondering about two ways to do it.

1. I create database schema in my 'symfony-db-test' and fixtures before all my tests but in this case can I create a doctrine.yaml in config/package/test to add the db-test connection infos ?
2. In PhpUnit : Create tables and fixtures in the setUp() function before each test ?